# Is there a way to create an entity dynamically without a definition file?

Tags: php, entity, drupal-8

Do I necessary need a definition file (like Drupal\entity_test_update\Entity\EntityTestNew) to create an entity in Drupal8?

```
$definition [
'id' => 'id',
'uuid' => 'uuid',
];
\Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager()
->installEntityType(new ContentEntityType($definition));
```